# Angular get JSON object with ':'

Tags: angularjs

I will receive one json object and need to get the value from particular filed which may contain namespace sometimes and may not

```
Example
ns2:employeeNumber and employeeNumber
```

I need to get the employeeNumber from JSON in angular

Is there possible in angular?

I can use

```
if(jsonObj[employeeNumber]){
//Code
}else if(jsonObj[ns2:employeeNumber){

}
```

ns2:employeeNumber : '121' or employeeNumber:'1212'

but want to any generic way?

new to Angular not sure about this

Comment: This doesn't look like an angularjs question but rather javascript. Please share the JSON or part of it demonstrating the asked question. If the property you're trying to retrieve from the JSON looks like `ns2:employeeNumber` then you can access it using `jsonObj["ns2:employeeNumber"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (typeof $scope.obj.employeeNumber != 'undefined') {
        console.log($scope.obj.employeeNumber);
} else {
        console.log($scope.obj['ns2:employeeNumber']);    
}
```